# GWT CellTable Style Overriding

Tags: css, gwt

After overriding the cellTable Style the font size for celltable is not working for rows other than the header.
I changed the font size for Celltable header and it is working. But for other rows the font size doesn't change. Even if I change the other properties like color for cellTableCell it's working only the font-size in cellTableCell is not working. I tried in IE 8 and chrome.

Any help is appreciated.

```css
.cellTableHeader {
    border: solid 1px  #ffffff;
    background: #D3E0F2;
 color: blue;
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 text-align: left;
}

.cellTableCell {
   border: solid 1px #ffffff;
   font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
   text-align: left;
   color: red;
   font-size:30px;
}​
```

Comment: Use F12 and view the code behind. Check if the CSS is being overridden by a style below it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
font-size:30px !important;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding !important but it's not working.

Comment: Look in your browser. Which style is overriding the font size?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses and especially for the F12 tip. Our application standard Css style was applying font size for Div element which was overriding CellTable css. After removing the font size style for DIV element from standard CSS the CellTableCell style works.